# Building npm module from external js api file

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, webgl-earth

I'm trying to build an npm package from [this repo](https://github.com/webglearth/webglearth2), I have the "minified" js file, which IntelliJ downloads when seeing the `<script src="">` tag, the file is called `http_www.webglearth.com_v2_api.js`

So, I've followed instructions as per [npm official](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules) and [treehouse](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/build-npm-package), but keep getting an `npm ERR! not a package` error message every time I try to do `npm install` on the project, I have uploaded my [attempt](https://github.com/Steven-Garcia/web_gl_earth_npm) to my Git-hub account, this is what the package.json looks like:

```
 {
  "name": "(web_gl_earth_module)",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "An npm package to help integrate WEBGL Earth to Angular apps",
  "main": "http_www.webglearth.com_v2_api.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "(https://github.com/webglearth/webglearth2.git)"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "webglearth",
    "globe",
    "visualisation"
  ],
  "author": " (git_hub accounts: petrsloup, klokan)",
  "license": "(Apache-2.0)"
}
```

I've had a browse for similar errors, but no case scenario really matches my issue, I'm not sure that I'm attempting this the right way or that it's even feasible.

My final goal is to be able to import this repository into an Angular project, which is now completely impossible

Comment: I'm really a noob when it comes down to JavaScript, so this question may be naive, silly and full of fundamental errors please excuse me if it is that bad, but I've been three days on this and starting to get really frustrated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've managed to build my npm and bower package using the whole repository rather than the min file.  The issue was really stupid.

When following the [treehouse tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/build-npm-package) I find this command for installing the package:

[image]

Now, one would think that `treehouse/` is the main directory and `treehouse_profile.js` is a javascript file, wrong...  `treehouse_profile.js` is the root folder  Lesson learned: careful where you pick your tutorials

Here's screenshot of the name of the repo in gitHub:

[image]

So, left with the angular integration, that's another good one, you can follow up in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50413854/wrap-google-closure-library-variables-for-angular-project)

Answer (score 0):

The name & version in package.json should be unique as compared available npm packages repo